# Raw tf-idf on elasticsearch

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm looking for a really scalable method to do tf-idf searching on a large dataset, so elastic search naturally came to mind.  Upon reading the default methods they use for scoring, it seems that none actually do raw tf-idf.  The closest is their ["Practical Scoring Function"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html#practical-scoring-function), but this combines a query norm, coordination factor, etc.  I've attached Lucene's formula below.

[image]

Is there any way to get elastic search to return a raw tf-idf score without any of the additional fluff?  I've tested each of the built-in implementations and none work as well as just tf-idf.

Raw tf-idf in this application would just be -

[image]

[image]

Also, I'm using one of the AWS provisioned elaticsearch instances, so I don't have access to the internals of the Java code.  Only the REST API.

Comment: it might make sense to take some time and explain what you refer with raw tf-idf to? you can disable normalization and boosting is optional, what else needs to be removed in order to make everything ok for you?

Comment: @alr Added a comment - I'd need the square idf term removed, as well as the norm and coord term.

Comment: ah, got it. I think it might make most sense to write your own similarity (check the lucene javadocs for more) and plug it in via a custom elasticsearch plugin.